Include AD server name on each record using PowerShell
I was provided with a PowerShell script that was created to get user information from all of our AD servers. Since we are querying multiple AD servers we'd like to include the name of the server for each employee record so it's clear which server contains which users.
Here is the original PowerShell script:
$paramlist = @("EmailAddress", "distinguishedname", "name", "GivenName", "surname", "SamAccountName",  "Userprincipalname", "Department", "title", "manager", "displayName", "company", "mail")
$outputfile = "C:\AD_Listing_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"

$Server = "Canada.bz"
get-aduser -server $server -filter * -properties $paramlist | Select-Object $paramlist | Export-Csv -Path $outputfile
$Server = "Europe.bz"
get-aduser -server $server -filter * -properties $paramlist | Select-Object $paramlist | Export-Csv -Append -Path $outputfile
$Server = "US.bz"
get-aduser -server $server -filter * -properties $paramlist | Select-Object $paramlist | Export-Csv -Append -Path $outputfile
$Server = "UK.bz"
get-aduser -server $server -filter * -properties $paramlist | Select-Object $paramlist | Export-Csv -Append -Path $outputfile
$Server = "Asia.bz"
get-aduser -server $server -filter * -properties $paramlist | Select-Object $paramlist | Export-Csv -Append -Path $outputfile

I'm just starting to learn about PowerShell and I've searched Stack and other sites but I can't align it to the code I was provided. I don't want to group results by server, I just want the server name to appear as another value at the end of each row.
Any suggestions or assistance would be appreciated.

Define an array of Domains you want to query, then enumerate each domain and pass it as argument of the -Server parameter and lastly, use a calculated property with Select-Object to attach the source domain:
$paramlist = "EmailAddress", "DistinguishedName", "Name" # ... other attributes to query
$outputfile = "C:\AD_Listing_$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"

$domains = 'Canada.bz', 'Europe.bz', 'US.bz', 'UK.bz', 'Asia.bz'
$domains | ForEach-Object {
    $domain = $_
    Get-ADUser -Server $domain -Filter * -Properties $paramlist |
        Select-Object @(
            @{ Name = 'Domain'; E = { $domain }}
            $paramlist)
} | Export-Csv -Path $outputfile


Ir might be shorter and more clear to use foreach ($domain in $domains) {. Is there any meaningful difference?

@lit wouldn't be able to stream output to | Export-Csv -Path $outputfile in which case a wrapping invoked scriptblock & { ... } | Export-Csv ... would be needed and that would be even more confusing for OP

Great - that's exactly what I was looking for. I'll go over your solution to understand and learn for next time. Much appreciated!
